# I'm just running " npm install -g @angular/cli" and i get this error

Tags: angular

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! path C:\Users\dmx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\dmx\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\dmx\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng' -> 'C:\Users\dmx\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd'
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\dmx\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\dmx\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-18T02_41_50_941Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Did you try to "Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
with --force to overwrite files recklessly."?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried either reinstalling NPM or running `npm cache clean`? Not sure if that will help but that is where I would start.

Comment: try npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is existed file with the same name or something or same defines. try run npm after if you fail   **Thats it!**